# Using z-index in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

check this code please https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zer8p7?file=modal.js

I have the modal and inside of it the Drawer component. How can i put the Drawer component above the Modal? I tried Z-index but it didn't work.

Thank you

Comment: Modals are rendered at the <body> level, so adjusting a z-index is probably not going to work. Asking to check code through a link instead of posting the relevant parts inside your question is likely to get you downvotes (just a fyi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the following in your `<Drawer>` in `drawer.js`. Make it look like this:

```
<Drawer
  anchor={anchor}
  open={state[anchor]}
  onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
  sx={{ zIndex: 1300}}
>
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: Ahh, common, i tried only tried zIndex:999  hahaha. Thanks

Comment: Could you help me one more time? I changed the code a bit, i added a selector component, but when it shows the options, the options get behind the Drawer. I tried zIndex in a few parts, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: replace the above with  `sx={{ zIndex: 1300 }}`. this will resolve everything or Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Indeed it worked! Why 1300? Is there any reason ?

Comment: It is 1300 because the z-index of the modal was 1300 while the z-index of drawer was 1200. by doing zIndex:1300 we said that hey use this as your z-index. now they all have same z-index so it automatically decides what should on top of what. if we give more than that it will be on top of everything and anything having less than that will move backwards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you tried adding z-index but try adding:

```
MuiDrawer-root{
  z-index:1300;
}
```

to

```
style.css
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need this behavior for specific circumstances, you can set the `zIndex` on the `Dialog` to `auto` using the `style` or `sx` prop and then the drawer will display above the dialog

```
sx={{ zIndex: 'auto' }}
```

or

```
style={{ zIndex: 'auto' }}
```